Debounced Completer autoselects highlighted option when I stop arrowing through results?
I'm trying to create a debounced Typeahead widget that populates with data from my database. When I try to down arrow through the query results, the highlighted result autoselects when I stop pressing the down arrow key.
I looked at the docs for the QCompleter and the return type of popup, QAbstractItemView. QAbstractItemView, says Ctrl+Arrow keys, "Changes the current item but does not select it.". However, when I try navigating with the Ctrl key held, the behavior is no different.
The code for my widget is below:
# Typeahead.h
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QLineEdit
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QCompleter
from utk_apis.sql_engine import SQLEngine
from PyQt5.QtCore import QStringListModel


from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer, QStringListModel
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QLineEdit, QCompleter, QAbstractItemView


class Typeahead(QLineEdit):
   def __init__(self, parent=None):
       super(Typeahead, self).__init__(parent)
       self.results = []
       self.selected_result = None
       self.engine = None
       self.current_index = -1
       self.ignore_text_change = False
       self.completer = QCompleter(self)
       
       self.completer.setWidget(self)
       self.completer.setCompletionMode(QCompleter.PopupCompletion)
       self.completer.popup().setSelectionMode(
           QAbstractItemView.SingleSelection
       )  # Single item selection in popup
       
       self.setCompleter(self.completer)
       self.completer.popup().setAlternatingRowColors(True)

       # Create a timer for debouncing
       self.debounce_timer = QTimer(self)
       self.debounce_timer.setSingleShot(True)  # Only trigger once after interval
       self.debounce_timer.setInterval(300)  # 300 ms debounce interval

       # Connect the timeout of the timer to the emit_text_changed method
       self.debounce_timer.timeout.connect(self.emit_text_changed)

       # Connect the textChanged signal to start the debounce timer
       self.textChanged.connect(self.start_debounce)

       # Connect the completer's activated signal to set the selected item only when Enter is pressed
       self.completer.activated.connect(self.on_completer_activated)
       

   def start_debounce(self):
       """Start the debounce timer when the text changes."""
       self.debounce_timer.start()  # This starts or restarts the debounce timer

   def emit_text_changed(self):
       """Fetch results and update completer when text changes."""
       print(f'Emitting text changed event: {self.text()} Ignore text change: {self.ignore_text_change}')

       if self.ignore_text_change is True:
           self.ignore_text_change = False
           return
       if self.engine is None:
           self.engine = SQLEngine(env=self.property("env"))

       # Run the query to fetch data from the database
       data = self.engine.run_query(self._build_query(), results_as_dict=True)

       # Convert data to the list of results. Store for sharing with other Typeahead instances
       self.results = [
           {
               "text": f"{row['primary_key_1']} ({row['primary_key_2']}, {row['primary_key_3']})",
               "primary_key_1": row["primary_key_1"],
               "primary_key_2": row["primary_key_2"],
               "primary_key_3": row["primary_key_3"],
           }
           for row in data
       ]

       # Update the completer with the new results
       self.update_completer()

   def update_completer(self):
       """Update the QCompleter with the new results."""
       completer_model = QStringListModel([result["text"] for result in self.results])
       
       #self.completer.model().setStringList(completer_model)
       self.completer.setModel(completer_model)

       # Set the width of the popup based on the longest string to avoid truncation
       longest_string = max(
           [len(result["text"]) for result in self.results], default=0
       )
       
       self.completer.popup().setMinimumWidth(
           longest_string * 15
       )  # Adjust 7 to fit font size

       # Manually open the completer dropdown
       if self.results:
           self.completer.complete()  # Force the dropdown to show up again

   def on_completer_activated(self, text):
       """Handle what happens when an item in the dropdown is selected."""
       # Only set the text when the user selects an item by pressing Enter
       selected_item = next(
           (result for result in self.results if result["text"] == text), None
       )
       if selected_item:
           self.setText(selected_item["text"])

   def _build_query(self):
       """Build the SQL query for fetching suggestions."""
       query = f"SELECT {','.join(self.property('primary_keys'))} FROM {self.property('targetTable')} WHERE {self.property('targetField')} LIKE '%{self.text()}%'"
       return query




Try with self.completer.popup().selectionModel().selectionChanged.disconnect() after setting the completer. It should work, but be aware that it may have unexpected results (I've not deeply checked the ramifications of completely disconnecting that signal, but in theory it should do fundamentally the same as QCompleter does).

You're the best! This fixed it. Updating the codeblock to show where the added line is.

Please don't edit the question to show the answer, instead revert the post and use the "Answer your question" to show what you actually changed. Also note that there's no point in doing self.completer.setWidget(self) since self.setCompleter(self.completer) will do it in any case. You can also remove the setSelectionMode() line, as the default view already uses SingleSelection. Finally, it's good habit to not overwrite existing members with different types: completer() is the dynamic getter of QLineEdit's completer, and should not be overwritten with its direct attribute reference.

One last thing: you should never use arbitrary values when setting sizes of widgets that display text. If you want to ensure that the completer always shows the full text of each completion, either use the popup's sizeHintForColumn(0) or QFontMetrics functions; possibly consider the vertical scroll bar's sizeHint().width().

The corrected code from musicmante is below. The line self.completer.popup().selectionModel().selectionChanged.disconnect() was added:
# Typeahead.h
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QLineEdit
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QCompleter
from utk_apis.sql_engine import SQLEngine
from PyQt5.QtCore import QStringListModel


from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer, QStringListModel
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QLineEdit, QCompleter, QAbstractItemView


class Typeahead(QLineEdit):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Typeahead, self).__init__(parent)
        self.results = []
        self.selected_result = None
        self.engine = None
        self.current_index = -1
        self.ignore_text_change = False
        self.completer = QCompleter(self)

        
        
        self.completer.setCompletionMode(QCompleter.PopupCompletion)
        
        self.setCompleter(self.completer)
        self.completer.popup().setAlternatingRowColors(True)

        # Create a timer for debouncing
        self.debounce_timer = QTimer(self)
        self.debounce_timer.setSingleShot(True)  # Only trigger once after interval
        self.debounce_timer.setInterval(300)  # 300 ms debounce interval

        # Connect the timeout of the timer to the emit_text_changed method
        self.debounce_timer.timeout.connect(self.emit_text_changed)

        # Connect the textChanged signal to start the debounce timer
        self.textChanged.connect(self.start_debounce)

        # Connect the completer's activated signal to set the selected item only when Enter is pressed
        self.completer.activated.connect(self.on_completer_activated)
        

    def start_debounce(self):
        """Start the debounce timer when the text changes."""
        self.debounce_timer.start()  # This starts or restarts the debounce timer

    def emit_text_changed(self):
        """Fetch results and update completer when text changes."""
        print(f'Emitting text changed event: {self.text()} Ignore text change: {self.ignore_text_change}')

        if self.ignore_text_change is True:
            self.ignore_text_change = False
            return
        if self.engine is None:
            self.engine = SQLEngine(env=self.property("env"))

        # Run the query to fetch data from the database
        data = self.engine.run_query(self._build_query(), results_as_dict=True)

        # Convert data to the list of results
        self.results = [
            {
                "text": f"{row['primary_key_1']} ({row['primary_key_2']}, {row['primary_key_3']})",
                "primary_key_1": row["primary_key_1"],
                "primary_key_2": row["primary_key_2"],
                "primary_key_3": row["primary_key_3"],
            }
            for row in data
        ]

        # Update the completer with the new results
        self.update_completer()

    def update_completer(self):
        """Update the QCompleter with the new results."""
        completer_model = QStringListModel([result["text"] for result in self.results])
        
        self.completer.setModel(completer_model)
        
        # THIS LINE STOPS THE DROPDOWN FROM CLOSING WHEN DOWN ARROW IS PRESSED
        self.completer.popup().selectionModel().selectionChanged.disconnect()

        # Set the width of the popup based on the longest string to avoid truncation
        longest_string = max(
            [len(result["text"]) for result in self.results], default=0
        )
        
        self.completer.popup().setMinimumWidth(
            longest_string * 15
        )  # Adjust 7 to fit font size

        # Manually open the completer dropdown
        if self.results:
            self.completer.complete()  # Force the dropdown to show up again

    def on_completer_activated(self, text):
        """Handle what happens when an item in the dropdown is selected."""
        # Only set the text when the user selects an item by pressing Enter
        selected_item = next(
            (result for result in self.results if result["text"] == text), None
        )
        if selected_item:
            self.setText(selected_item["text"])

    def _build_query(self):
        """Build the SQL query for fetching suggestions."""
        query = f"SELECT {','.join(self.property('primary_keys'))} FROM {self.property('targetTable')} WHERE {self.property('targetField')} LIKE '%{self.text()}%'"
        return query

